# A faster way to compute percentage correlation between two filter functions

Tags: python, performance

I wrote this function to compute the normalized percentage correlation between two filter functions (with one shifted). The function works but takes about 8 to 12 minutes depending on the number of elements in nbs. I would like to know if there is another way to make this operation faster. Here is my code below:

```
import numpy as np

DT = 0.08
def corr_g(*nbs, Np=10000, sf = 0.5):
    wb = 0.25 # bandwidth in Hz
    freq = (1/DT)*np.linspace(-0.5,0.5-1/Np,Np) # frequency vector
    dCg_norms = np.zeros((Np,len(nbs)))
    for idx, nb in enumerate(nbs): # nb is the filter parameter
        d_k_vector = np.linspace(-Np*sf, Np*sf, Np) # indices vector 
        dCg = d_k_vector*0 # array to hold correlation
        g = ((1+np.exp(-nb))**2)/((1+np.exp(-nb*(freq+wb)/wb))*(1+np.exp(nb*(freq-wb)/wb))) # filter function
        for index2, d_k in enumerate(d_k_vector): # loop through the new indices vector
            for index, sth in enumerate(g): 
            # form a new array from g using the indices vector use only values within the limits of g. Then do a dot product operation
                if (index+d_k) < Np and (index+d_k)  >= 0:
                    dCg[index2] += g[index] * g[index+int(d_k)]

        dCg_norm = dCg/np.max(dCg)*100 # normalized correlation
        dCg_norms[:,idx] = dCg_norm # add to allocated array

    return dCg_norms


my_arr = corr_g(*[2,4,8,16])
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Np = 10000
DT = 0.08
d_k_vector = np.linspace(-5000, 5000, Np)
plt.plot(d_k_vector/(10000*DT)/0.25,my_arr[:,1])
```

Comment: Can you perhaps explain how the code relates to your task? I am having a hard time figuring out where in that code there are two filter functions; explaining the algorithm in words and using speaking names instead of abbreviations/single-letters would likely be helpful.

Comment: Hi MisterMiyagi, I added some comment. basically the calculation within the for loop is what slows down the computation. The d_k_vector is used as index to shift the original g (filter) array.

Answer (score 1):

You should not calculate correlation yourself, better use `np.correlate(vector, 'same')`. There are small differences between your result and mine and I am pretty sure error is on your side.

```
def corr_g2(*nbs, Np=10000, sf = 0.5):
    wb = 0.25 # bandwidth in Hz
    freq = (1/DT)*np.linspace(-0.5,0.5-1/Np,Np) # frequency vector
    dCg_norms = np.zeros((Np,len(nbs)))
    for idx, nb in enumerate(nbs): # nb is the filter parameter
        g = ((1+np.exp(-nb))**2)/((1+np.exp(-nb*(freq+wb)/wb))*(1+np.exp(nb*(freq-wb)/wb))) # filter function
        dCg = np.correlate(g, g, 'same')
        dCg_norm = dCg/np.max(dCg)*100 # normalized correlation
        dCg_norms[:,idx] = dCg_norm # add to allocated array

    return dCg_norms

def main():
    my_arr = corr_g(*[2,4], Np=Np)
    my_arr2 = corr_g2(*[2,4], Np=Np)
    # import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    # d_k_vector = np.linspace(-Np / 2, Np / 2 - 1, Np)
    # plt.plot(d_k_vector/(10000*DT)/0.25,my_arr[:,1])
    # plt.plot(d_k_vector/(10000*DT)/0.25,my_arr2[:,1])
    # plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Profiling results for `Np=1000`:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    39                                           @do_profile()
    40                                           def main():
    41         1   14419637.0 14419637.0    100.0      my_arr = corr_g(*[2,4], Np=Np)
    42         1       1598.0   1598.0      0.0      my_arr2 = corr_g2(*[2,4], Np=Np)
```